# How to use Lumen with Angular2+?

Tags: laravel, angular, lumen

How to use Lumen with Angular2+ ? I know how to use both of them separately but do not know how to use them combine. A brief directory structure would be really helpful if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please be more specific on what you tried and didn't work, maybe some code examples.

Comment: There are a variety of ways of doing this, including entirely separate repositories and folder structures for frontend and backend.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz your comment was helpful. I created both repo separately and did some searches that how connect them both. And it works :) . Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [repo](https://github.com/jaesung2061/anvel) uses Laravel (the big brother of Lumen). You can use it or use the folder logic to implement it with Lumen.

An older [repo](https://github.com/CreativeBrandon/Angular2-Lumen) works with Lumen.

P.S. [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=lumen%20angular2&oq=lumen%20angular2&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0.2588j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) "lumen angular2" and you will find both projects as the first results...

Comment: Thanks mimo your answer was really helpful.